# objective-c how to use singleton?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I want to use some singleton class. I've created it but don't know how to use it in my viewControllers.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppData : NSObject

//Singletone
+(AppData*)sharedInstance;
 @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *shardString;

 //Refs

 @end
```

AppData.m:

```
#import "AppData.h"

static AppData* staticInstance;
@implementation AppData 

+(AppData*)sharedInstance
  {
if (staticInstance==nil)
{

    staticInstance=[AppData new];

}

 return staticInstance;
}

@end
```

Now I need to give value of qwerty NSString to singleton's object and how to get access from another viewControllers to this object?
ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppData.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSString *qwerty = @"i'm a singlton!";

[[AppData sharedInstance] ]

NSLog(@"%@",);

}
```

Comment: You're basically already there: `[[AppData sharedInstance] setShardString:qwerty]` (or `setSharedString` depending on whether that's a typo).  One thing, though, is to look at singleton creation examples that use `dispatch_once`.  You may not need the thread safety now, but you will.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You access the property just Ike you would for any other object.

```
[AppData sharedInstance].sharedString = @"foo";
```

Or

```
NSString *foo =  [AppData sharedInstance].sharedString;
```

Comment: I want to add one more variable of type NSInteger to singleton (@property (strong,nonatomic) NSInteger *sharedInt;)but I get:  property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type. How to fix?

Comment: NSInteger is a primitive type, not an object type. It needs to be `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger sharedInt;`.

Comment: FYI - please don't forget to accept answers that solve your questions. You've only accepted a single answer for all of your questions.